# Angular2,How to broadcast event from parent component to child directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

In Angular1,It has the `$scope.braodcast`.and the `EventEmitter` in Angular2 can only emit an event from child to parent. So how can I broadcast the event to a child directive?

**this is my child directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, OnInit } from   '@angular/core';

import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({ 
  selector: '[svgLine]'
})


export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
  ) {}
  @Input() svgLineClientWidth: number;
  @Input() svgLineClientHeight: number;
  @Input() svgToClientWidth: number;
  @Input() svgToClientHeight: number;
  @Input() svgLineFromId: number;
  @Input() svgLineToId: number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
      // receive the event
  }
}
```

**and this is my parent component**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
    import { Tools } from '../class/tools'
    import { DetailListService } from './detail-list.service';

    @Component({
        // moduleId使用于CommonJs
        moduleId : module.id,
        selector : 'detail-list',
        templateUrl : './detail-list.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./detail-list.component.css'],
    })

    export class DetailListComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(
          private detailListService : DetailListService,
      ) {}
      clickItem() {
        // broadcast the event here
      }
    }
```

**detail-list.component.html**

```
    <svg  class="svg--position">
        <g *ngFor="let item of model.data">
            <g pointer-events="painted"
                svgLine
                *ngFor="let to of item.to"
                [svgLineClientWidth]="item.clientWidth"
                [svgLineClientHeight]="item.clientHeight"
                [svgToClientWidth]="to.clientWidth"
                [svgToClientHeight]="to.clientHeight"
                [svgLineFromId]="item.id"
                [svgLineToId]="to.id"             
                id="{{item.title}}{{item.id}}{{to.id}}"
            >                     
            </g>
        </g>

    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to do it. But I'd go with minimum configuration.

**ParentComponent**

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

export class DetailListComponent implements OnInit {

  ViewChild('svgLine') vc:svgLine;
     //  you can have an access over svgLine diretive

  clickItem() {
    // broadcast the event here

       this.vc.printf('Angular2');

    //   Not sure if it can call ngOnInit as haven't tested it ever. 
    //   But you can try calling and see if works.
    //   this.vc.onInit() something
  }
}
```

**svgLineDirective**

```
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit {     
  ngOnInit(): void {
      // receive the event
  }

  printf(message:string){
      alert(message);
  }
}
```

For child to parent, you can use **output** api with **EventEmitter** api. thousands of examples are available for that.

Comment: how can I get the directive's id in the directive,like the $attrs.id in angular1?

Comment: Inject ElementRef into the directive to get access to the element it decorates